# Optimize a all related field search method

Tags: php, mysql

Id like to see if there is any better way that i could optimized the following search method.

I am completely aware that i am currently returning some un-used field from my mysql query. I plan on actually using them. So I don't "double fetch" data once I am using the `Customer` `constructor`

```
        static function ByAny($SearchString){
            $Get = dbCon::$dbCon -> prepare("
SELECT cC.Id as cC_Id,cC.FirstName as cC_FirstName,cC.LastName as cC_LastName,cC.EmailAddress as cC_EmailAddress,cC.Note as cC_Note,
    cF.Id as cF_Id,cF.Name as cF_Name, cF.Notes as cF_Note,
    cA.Address as cA_Address, cA.City as cA_City, cA.PostalCode as cA_PostalCode,cA.Province as cA_Province, cA.Country as cA_Country,cA.Description as cA_Description,
    cFA.Address as cFA_Address, cFA.City as cFA_City, cFA.PostalCode as cFA_PostalCode,cFA.Province as cFA_Province, cFA.Country as cFA_Country,cFA.Description as cFA_Description
FROM
    `customer_customers` as cC
        LEFT JOIN customer_farms as cF ON (cC.FarmId = cF.Id)
        LEFT JOIN addresses as cA ON (cC.AddressId = cA.Id)
        LEFT JOIN addresses as cFA ON (cF.AddressId = cFA.Id)
WHERE
    CONCAT_WS(
        cC.FirstName,' ',cC.LastName,' ',cC.EmailAddress,' ',cC.Note,' ',
        cF.Name,' ',cF.Notes,' ',
        cA.Address,' ',cA.City,' ',cA.PostalCode,' ',cA.Province,' ',cA.Country,' ',cA.Description,
        cFA.Address,' ',cFA.City,' ',cFA.PostalCode,' ',cFA.Province,' ',cFA.Country,' ',cFA.Description
    ) LIKE :Like;
            ");

            $CustomerObjAr = array();

            $SearchResult = null;
            foreach(explode(' ',$SearchString) as $Q){ //Explode string by spaces, then search all words
                $Get -> bindValue(':Like','%'.$Q.'%');
                try{
                    $Get -> execute();

                    if(is_null($SearchResult)){ // Is first time search run, All result should be kept.
                        $SearchResult = array();
                        foreach($Get->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $cData){
                            $SearchResult[] = $cData['cC_Id'];
                        }
                    }else{ // We already have result, lets compare them with new result, and keep only matching ( Closing narrowing search result )
                        $cSearchResult = array();
                        foreach($Get->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $cData){
                            $cSearchResult[] = $cData['cC_Id'];
                        }
                        $SearchResult = array_intersect($SearchResult,$cSearchResult);
                    }
                    if(is_array($SearchResult) && count($SearchResult) == 0) //No more result, lets terminate this now.
                        return $SearchResult;

                }catch (\PDOException $e){
                    die("Error while searching customers by any field: ".$e->getMessage());
                }
            }
            foreach($SearchResult as $cId){
                $CustomerObjAr[] = new Customer($cId);
            }
            return $CustomerObjAr;
        }
```

I was thinking to add a `IN (1,2,3)` Clause of the already known matching result, But I am un-certain of the actual benefits of providing a list, Would it speedthings up on mysql side ? or will it slow it down by first selecting those and then runing `CONCAT() LIKE`?

Thanks for input and constructive criticism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method you are doing, `CONCAT() LIKE ?` is bound to do a table-scan. So it will get slower in direct proportion to the size of your table.

If you need to do a fulltext search across multiple columns, and you want it to run efficiently, you should learn about [MySQL's fulltext search functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-search.html).

I did a presentation comparing the old-school `LIKE '%pattern%'` type queries versus searches using fulltext indexes. It depends on how much data you have, but fulltext indexes can make your queries *hundreds or thousands of times faster* than doing searches like you're doing it.

See my presentation: [Fulltext Search Throwdown](https://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/practical-full-text-search-with-my-sql).

Comment: Great presentation, I like the fact that you included so many stats.
I will for sure investigate futher into fulltext search